# Zend_Db_Select help with join

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join, zend-db-select

i'm using the following code and get the following error

```
$select = $model->select();
$select->from(array('stocktakejob'), 
            array("ProductID" => "stocktakejob.ProductID",
                    "TotalCount" => "SUM(stocktakejob.NewCount)"
              )
       )->join(array('products'),
               'products.ProductID = stocktakejob.ProductID', 
               array("ProductCode" => "products.ProductCode")
       )->where("stocktakejob.StockTakeID = ".$stocktake->getStockTakeID())
       ->group('stocktakejob.ProductID');
```

error: Exception

```
Select query cannot join with another table
```

Is there something i'm missing ? anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should set integrity check to false when making join statements:

```
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

Comment: that was the answer thanks a million. cant believe i was missing that.